# Cocoapods could not find compatible versions for pod from several frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift4

I received this error log when pod install.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RxSwift":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    RxSwift (= 4.1.2, ~> 4.0)

  In Podfile:
    FrameworkA (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.0.4, which depends on
      RxSwift (~> 4.0)

    FrameworkB (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
      RxSwift (~> 3.0)
```

I understand what is problem. because of two frameworks are needed same library but different versions. (... right?)

But I must use that versions that FrameworkA is `~> 4.0` and FrameworkB is `~> 1.0`.

What are the solutions in my case?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to have different version of a same pod. In your case, "hidden" ones imported with a dependency. You need to manage a version that can use the same version of RxSwift. Update FrameworkB to support RxSwift 4?